# Better picture->ASCII art converter, that takes character shapes into account

Tags: gratis, images, image-processing, ocr

Typical picture to AA converter just treats all output characters as pixels, considering only it's overall boldness.

I want Image -> Ascii Art converter that uses OCR technologies and choses characters that are most similar to the parts of input image (even if somewhat displaced). Ideally it should also preserve some text.

Example of conversion (manually done):

[image: sample of source image]

```
    __
   |
    \_   C
┌------------\
|              \
|                \ T   T
|                 --------┐
| Hello, world.           |
|                         \
\                   ______/
 ------------------/
```

Preferably FOSS running on Linux or portable, no budget.

Comment: An can you explain "preserve some text"? Are you saying that there is text in the images? If so, how ought it to be preserved?

Comment: @Mawg, By doing monospace-adjusted OCR. Added sample to illustrate.

Comment: Is that Doctor Who's K9?  When I was young I came home from school one day and announced that "the teacher is stupid - I drew a horse and she didn't even know what it was!"  :-)

Comment: @Mawg, No, I don't know about Doctor Who or K9 [yet]. I just drew something boxartesque, some additional lines resembling characters and the text inside.

Comment: Apologies for being flippant. It's the first thing that sprang to mind (I can't believe anyone doesn't know Doctor Who !) http://www.thinkgeek.com/images/products/zoom/ed66_exclusive_doctor_who_k9_figure.jpg